# Finding $n$ paths on a graph with minimal overlapping

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, algorithms

Suppose I have a simple undirected graph $G = (V, E)$ and $n$ pairs of sources and destinations $(s_i, d_i)$.

Is there any existing algorithm to find a set of $n$ paths between those sources and destinations while trying to minimize edge overlapping between those $n$ paths?

What are keywords I should use when searching?

Comment: Search for multicommodity flow and load balancing, see also [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-commodity_flow_problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There is an algorithm](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895611000712) that builds set of edge-disjoint paths between given pairs of vertices using $O(n^2)$ time. If there was some algorithm for a weighted version of this problem then your problem would be solvable using this algorithm.

Comment: Can algorithms for edge-disjoint path problems handle the cases when any solution must have some overlapping as well?

Comment: So speaking about weighted version of edge-disjoint paths problem I mean that sum of weights of all edges included into paths should be minimized. Then in your case each edge of original graph will have weight 0 and will be copied several times with weight 1. Thus number of edge reuses in original graph will be minimized. (If you have some other meaning of "edge overlapping" you should clarify it.)

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can formulate this as a multicommodity flow problem and solve it via linear programming.

- The commodities are $K = \{ s_i \} \times \{ d_i \} $.
- Let $A$ be the arc set, with one arc in each direction for each edge in $E$.

  - For $(i,j)\in A$ and $k\in K$, let variable $x_{i,j}^k \ge 0$ be the flow along arc $(i,j)$ of commodity $k$.
- Let variable $y_{i,j}\ge 0$ be the amount by which the total flow (in either direction) across edge $\{i,j\}\in E$ exceeds $1$.
- Let $b_{i,k}$ be the supply at node $i$ of commodity $k$. We must have that:

  - $b_{i,k} = 1$ for the source node of commodity $k$ (flow conservation at the source),
  - $b_{i,k} = -1$ for the sink node of commodity $k$ (flow conservation at the destination), and
  - $b_{i,k} = 0$ otherwise (flow conservation on transit nodes).

The linear program breaks down to:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ll@{}ll}
\text{minimize}  & \displaystyle\sum_{\{i,j\}\in E} y_{i,j}  &\\
\text{subject to}& \displaystyle\sum_{k\in K} (x_{i,j}^k + x_{j,i}^k) &\le 1 + y_{i,j} &\forall\{i,j\}\in E\\
& \displaystyle\sum_j (x_{i,j}^k - x_{j,i}^k) &= 0   &\forall i\neq s_i,d_i\in V \text{ and }\forall k\in K\\
& \displaystyle\sum_j (x_{s_i,j}^k - x_{j,s_i}^k) &= 1   &\forall k\in K\\
& \displaystyle\sum_j (x_{d_i,j}^k - x_{j,d_i}^k) &= -1  &\forall k\in K\\
\end{array}
\end{equation*}